# Multiple Web Callouts In Scheduled Apex

Tags: scheduled-apex, future, httprequest

I'm trying to get some additional information on specific phone numbers in my database using web callouts. I won't hit the governor limits as it's going to be less than 100 numbers per day. I'm also calling another API to supplement that additional information. This second callout is a post request that sends a list of the phone numbers + data, so just one callout. In total, I have two functions that include web callouts. To schedule this Apex, I see that I need to use the @future(callout=true) annotation on any function that makes a web callout. However, I know I'm limited to one future method per schedulable execution. Is there a workaround for this or any alternatives?

Comment: The options are well described in the [Asynchronous Apex](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/asynchronous_apex) Trailhead Module.

Answer (score 1):

You can make 100 callouts per transaction, so you might be able to just do it all in one future method. If you need multiple transactions for some reason, use Queueable, instead. Queueables can also make callouts, and can chain together to make multiple transactions. In addition, you can utilize the [Finalizer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm) interface to allow for error recovery.